# Как можно убрать рамку "border" вокруг иконки в "QMessageBox"?

Tags: c++, qt, qss, qt4

Пытаюсь изменить стиль в "QMessageBox", для этого сделал следующие:

```
   QMessageBox *mb = new QMessageBox(this);
   mb->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
   mb->setStyleSheet(  "QWidget {"
                                 "background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);"
                                 "border: 4px solid rgb(90,90,90);"
                                 "border-radius: 10px;"
                                 "border-color: black;"
                                "}"
                       "qt_msgboxex_icon_label {"
                                  "background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);"
                                  "border: 0px solid rgb(80,80,200); "
                                "}"
                    );
   QPushButton *OkButton = mb->addButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
   int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
   QFont font = QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first());
   font.setPointSize(14);
   OkButton->setFont(font);
   OkButton->setText(" OK ");
   OkButton->setStyleSheet(
                            "QAbstractButton {"
                            "color: #0000ff;"
                            "border: 4px solid rgb(80,80,200); "
                            "border-radius: 5px;"
                            "background-color: rgb(200,200,200);"
                            "}"

                            "QAbstractButton:pressed {"
                            "color: #0000ff;"
                            "border: 4px solid rgb(90,90,90); "
                            "border-radius: 5px;"
                            "background-color: rgb(200,200,200);"
                            "}"
                             );
   mb->setText("информация о состоянии\nномер 100\nемкость 75 А/ч");
   mb->exec();
   mb->deleteLater();
```

Проблема. Не могу убрать рамку вокруг иконки (показал на рисунки). Хочу просто отключить иконку и выравнивать текст в центре окна "QMessageBox".
Подскажите как можно сделать.

[image: изображение иконки в рамки без mb->setIcon(QMessageBox::NoIcon);]

[image: изображение иконки в рамки с mb->setIcon(QMessageBox::NoIcon);]

Comment: Она не из-за этой ли фигни там появлась `"border: 0px solid rgb(80,80,200); "` в `qt_msgboxex_icon_label `?

Comment: Это я пытался убрать рамку и добавил данный код в качестве эксперимента. Без данного кода рамка остается.

Comment: Скорее всего, рамка уже присутствует в самой иконке. Попробуйте свою иконку подставить: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601774/5909792

Comment: Мне нужно иконку убрать.

Comment: Тогда, к чему про рамку спрашивать? :)  Убрать еще проще: `mb->setIcon(QMessageBox::NoIcon)` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#icon-prop

Comment: Если я вызову метод mb->setIcon(QMessageBox::NoIcon) то рамка не уйдет. Только пропадет иконка. Приложил рисунок.

Comment: Потому что вы сами рамку и добавляете в setStyleSheet... Но я вангую, что ваша проблема в том, что остается место от иконки, а вы хотели освободить место, верно? Вместо того, чтобы бороться с этим диалогом, я бы посоветовал создать свой через QDialog

Comment: Текст поместить в `QLabel`, кнопки через `QDialogButtonBox`. Создаете класс от `QDIalog` и на него как на любого виджета размещаете другие виджеты через компоновщики, соединяете сигналы от `QDialogButtonBox` к слотам диалога и запускаете через `exec`. Будет почти тоже самое, но с безграничными возможностями кастомизации под свои нужды. Можно и в Qt Designer создать диалог